# cforest: error in predict when newdata is one-row dataframe

Tags: r, tree, predict, party

Hello I am using the package `partykit` and its function `cforest` to fit a model. I can also use `predict` to predict based on a multi-row dataframe. However, I cannot predict on a dataframe with one row.

```
require('partykit')
y <- matrix(rnorm(500*1),nrow=500,ncol=1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(500*6),nrow=500,ncol=6)
df <- data.frame(y=y,x=x)
obj = cforest(y ~ ., data= df)

#works
predict(obj,newdata=df)

# doesn't work
predict(obj,newdata=df[5,])

#this works
predict(obj,newdata=df[c(5,6),])
```

The error message is:

> predict(obj,newdata=df[5,]) Error in vector(mode = "list", length = ncol(w)) : invalid 'length' argument

Answer (score 3):

There does appear to be a bug in the code when you try to predict just one row. The function that's being called is `partykit:::predict.cforest`. And there's a line in there that says

```
return(pw[, match(fnewdata, ids)])
```

but it should be

```
return(pw[, match(fnewdata, ids), drop=FALSE])
```

So you can either always call it with one more than one row, or you can hack the function (this is very, very hacky and depends on line numbers in the function so it may break in the future -- tested with `partykit_1.0-5`) like so

```
mypredict <- partykit:::predict.cforest
body(mypredict)[[c(13,3,3,3,8)]] <- quote(return(pw[, match(fnewdata, ids), drop=FALSE]))
mypredict(obj, newdata=df[6,])
#          5 
# 0.04755628
```

Now we have a new function that should handle the case of one row correctly

Comment: An even better solution is to contact one of the `partykit` authors (not everyone is watching SO all of the time) and ask them to add your fix. This author has done so now and the fixed version will be available from R-Forge soon: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=261 Thanks for spotting this and suggesting the fix!